# Object doesn't support property or method '$1Q_0' when using cascading executeQueryAsync

Tags: javascript, jsom, taxonomy, typescript

I have a very annoying problem. I get the above error every time I execute below code. It happens at the second `executeQueryAsync` call. The error callback isn't hit nor did I find anything interesting in live ULS log. Does anybody see anything wrong with my code?

[image]

```
private bindFields() 
{
    console.log('Executing TaxonomyHelper.bindFields()');
    var self = this;
    this.list = this.context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(self.listName);
    this.context.load(this.list);
    this.context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        self.competenceField = self.list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle(self.competenceFieldName);
        self.technologyTopicField = self.list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle(self.technologyTopicFieldName);
        self.context.load(self.competenceField);
        self.context.load(self.technologyTopicField);
        self.context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            self.competenceTaxField = self.context.castTo(self.competenceField, SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField);
            self.competenceTaxField.set_sspId(self.defaultTermStore.get_id().toString());
            self.competenceTaxField.set_termSetId(self.competenceTermSetGuid);
            self.competenceField.updateAndPushChanges(true);

            self.technologyTopicTaxField = self.context.castTo(self.technologyTopicField, SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField);
            self.technologyTopicTaxField.set_sspId(self.defaultTermStore.get_id().toString());
            self.technologyTopicTaxField.set_termSetId(self.technologyTopicTermSetGuid);
            self.technologyTopicTaxField.updateAndPushChanges(true);

            self.context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                console.log('All finshed. Cleaning up now...');
                self.cleanUp();
            },
            function (sender, args) {
                console.log('Error in TaxonomyHelper.bindFields(): ' + args.get_message());
                self.cleanUp();
            });
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            console.log('Error in TaxonomyHelper.bindFields(): ' + args.get_message());
            self.cleanUp();
        });
    },
    function (sender, args) {
        console.log('Error in TaxonomyHelper.bindFields(): ' + args.get_message());
        self.cleanUp();
    });
}
```

EDIT: Refactored my code as below. Still yielded the same error.

```
private bindFields() 
{
    console.log('Executing TaxonomyHelper.bindFields()');
    var self = this;
    this.list = this.context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(this.listName);
    this.competenceField = this.list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle(this.competenceFieldName);
    this.technologyTopicField = this.list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle(this.technologyTopicFieldName);
    this.context.load(this.competenceField);
    this.context.load(this.technologyTopicField);
    this.context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        self.competenceTaxField = self.context.castTo(self.competenceField, SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField);
        self.competenceTaxField.set_sspId(self.defaultTermStore.get_id().toString());
        self.competenceTaxField.set_termSetId(self.competenceTermSetGuid);
        self.competenceField.updateAndPushChanges(true);

        self.technologyTopicTaxField = self.context.castTo(self.technologyTopicField, SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField);
        self.technologyTopicTaxField.set_sspId(self.defaultTermStore.get_id().toString());
        self.technologyTopicTaxField.set_termSetId(self.technologyTopicTermSetGuid);
        self.technologyTopicTaxField.updateAndPushChanges(true);

        self.context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            console.log('All finshed. Cleaning up now...');
            self.cleanUp();
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            console.log('Error in TaxonomyHelper.bindFields(): ' + args.get_message());
            self.cleanUp();
        });
    },
    function (sender, args) {
        console.log('Error in TaxonomyHelper.bindFields(): ' + args.get_message());
        self.cleanUp();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something with the `SP.ClientContext` that corrupts its internal data. But since your first `executeQueryAsync` is not necessary, you should have no problem to solve it.

Try this piece:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {
    var listName = 'example';
    var fieldNameA = 'yourfieldA';
    var fieldNameB = 'yourfieldB';

    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
    var listFields = list.get_fields();

    var fieldA = listFields.getByTitle(fieldNameA);
    fieldA = ctx.castTo(fieldA, SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField);
    fieldA.set_termSetId('valueA');
    fieldA.update();

    var fieldB = listFields.getByTitle(fieldNameB);
    fieldB = ctx.castTo(fieldB, SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField);
    fieldB.set_termSetId('valueB');
    fieldB.update();

    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
            console.log('success');
        },
        function(err, args) {
            console.log('error: ', args.get_message());
        });
});
```

Comment: I am in a refactoring process right now and my code is too messy to test your answer. but I will get back ASAP if this worked or not.

Comment: ok I just tried this and got another error when the first castTo() function was called: "Sys.ArgumentException: The value is outside the the expected range. Parameter name: type" (Sorry, just translated from german)